# How can I extract the contents of a web page with Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, xml, http, nokogiri

So for example, if I want to retrieve the movies that George Clooney has been in, I do something like this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'rubygems'

PAGE_URL = "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000123" # url for george clooneys profile on imdb
page = Nokogiri::XML(open(PAGE_URL))
puts page.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]").to_s
```

where I extracted the xpath using FireBug, but when I run the program, I just get a blank line in the terminal...so nothing actually happens? What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Don't use Firebug, or any browser-based tool to try to find a selector. Browsers do fixups on the markup prior to displaying the page, and Firebug will reflect those changes. The fixups can alter the HTML, adding/altering tags, which won't be in the HTML Nokogiri or your parser will see. Instead use `wget` or `curl` to look at the data, or use `nokogiri` itself at the command-line. Also, simplify your selector. There is never a need to use a long explicit CSS or XPath. Find place-markers in the document and navigate to those.

Comment: Also, you need to supply minimized HMTL demonstrating the problem. Don't expect us to wade through the entire page on a remote site. Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I used to get the titles:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

PAGE_URL = "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000123"
page = Nokogiri::XML(open(PAGE_URL))
page.css("div.filmo-category-section b a").each { |movie| puts movie.text }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've now been trying to get only the titles under the 'Actor' heading, but no luck..any suggestions?

Comment: Hm, for that, I'm not too sure. Using `page.css("div.filmo-category-section").children.each {|x| puts x.text }` grabs all the text within each of the divs, but since the character name isn't wrapped inside any html tags, I can't grab it directly with nokogiri. You may have to grab the entire thing, and parse the information to remove all `\n` and grabbing each relevant information.